# What are the risks of increasing the "Connection Time-out (seconds)" (IIS)?

Tags: iis, sharepoint, connection

We have the following situation at work: Currently we have problems with obtaining reports, which are generated through an application developed in .NET and is mounted on a SharePoint 2010 site. We have done tests generating reports of short time periods (per month) and it works perfect, the problem arises only when trying to obtain the report per year (due to the large number of records).

There are two servers, production and QA, the problem only occurs in the production environment (obviously it is the one with the highest workload).

We were reviewing the configurations of both servers and found the following difference in IIS:

PROD
Connection Time-out (seconds): 120

QA
Connection Time-out (seconds): 180

We would like to increase this time in the production environment, however we would like to know if there is any risk of impacting some other process / application.

Any recommendation?

Thank you

Comment: It would make the site more vulnerable to DDOS attack, as malformed connections would only be dropped after the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Connection timeouts help reduce the amount of memory resources that are consumed by idle connections. Time-out settings also allow you to specify how long server resources are allocated to specific tasks or clients.

When increasing the Time Out value, it will be good for large number records process, as it will need more time to connect to the IIS.